# PHP glob does not filter GIF

Tags: php

**uploads** folder has different types of images. I want just to show only .gif images on the web page. Why the image is not shown (see output screenshot)?

```
            $dir = "uploads";
        $allowedExts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

        if( file_exists($dir) == false ){
            echo 'Directory \''. $dir . '\' not found!';
        }
        else{
            //$dir_contents = scandir( $dir );
            $dir_contents = glob( $dir. "/*.gif" );

            foreach( $dir_contents as $file ){
                $exp_array = explode('.', strtolower($file));
                $extension = end($exp_array);

                if( in_array($extension, $allowedExts) ){
                    echo '<img src="'. $dir. '/'. $file. '" alt="'. $file. '" width="250" height="190" />'; 
                }
            }
        }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p11wn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just replace the following code in your code:

```
if( in_array($extension, $allowedExts) ){
    echo '<img src="'.$file. '" alt="'. $file. '" width="250" height="190" />'; 
}
```

Comment: Sir, it works!!! thanks. Please give me a brief explanation about it. Still I am trying to understand your solution.

Comment: Ok sir, I used print_r($dir_contents); Array ( [0] => uploads/(7).gif ). Then I understood. :)

Comment: Yes Tina, it was repeating the directory name in image source.